# Assigning a command to variable

Tags: bash, alias

I assign command `ls` to my variable `my_File` but when I run it as `$my_File` it does not work. Can you please explain why?

```
#!/bin/bash
my_File='ls -f | grep -v '\/''
$my_File
```

Comment: Try `my_File=$(ls -f | grep -v '\/')` or substitute the outer quotes by backquotes...

Comment: Why not use `alias`?

Comment: Seconding @Ketan's question, what is your motivation for wanting to do this?

Comment: What kind of quoting is `'ls -f | grep -v '\/''` supposed to be?

Comment: it has to list only files in $PWD

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The line you wrote defines a variable whose value is the string `ls -f | grep -v /`. When you use it unquoted, it expands to a list of words (the string is split at whitespace): `ls`, `-f`, `|`, `grep`, `-v`, `/`. The `|` character isn't special since the shell is splitting the string, not parsing it, so it becomes the second argument to the `ls` command.

You can't stuff a command into a string like this. To define a short name for a command, use an alias (if the command is complete) or a function (if the command has parameters and is anything more than passing some default arguments to a single command). In your case, an alias will do.

```
alias my_File='ls -f | grep -v /'
my_File
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ my_File='ls -f | grep -v '\/''
$ $my_File 
ls: cannot access |: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access grep: No such file or directory
[snip]
```

When interpreting `$my_File`, bash treats the characters in it as just characters.  Thus, for one, the command line has a literal `|` character in it, not a pipe.

If you are trying to execute `$my_File` on the command line and have the pipes work, you need `eval $my_File`.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "${var='ls -f | grep -v "\/"'}" |sh
```

You certainly need an interpreter - though not necessarily *`eval`.*

```
. <<-HEREDOC /dev/stdin
    $var
HEREDOC

echo "$var" | . /dev/stdin
```

There are a lot of ways to get there.

```
${0#-} -c "$var"

sh - c "$var"
```

Answer (score -1):

variable = `command`

backquote character(`)

so like 
var = `pwd`
echo $var = /home/user/foo

Comment: That would assign the _output_ of the command to the variable which is not what is being asked for here.